# R,Rename.file iteratively

Tags: r, file-rename

I'm trying to write an algorithm in R language which allows me to rename files. I want to rename all pdf files in a folder by numbers 1,2,3,4,5,... and keeping the pdf extension.
The main difficulty is the following: My folders contains files and folders and these folders contain files and folders etc.... I want that all pdf files in all these subfolders are named by numbers starting to 1 and going up to the number of files in this specific folder (following for example the alphabetic order)! Another difficulty: My folders also contain non-pdf files !

Here is an example:
(In the following example Folder 1 contains folder2 and 3 files. folder two contains 4 files.)

```
Folder1   "contains"   folder2     "contains"   Bzzz.file.R
                       A.file.txt               B.file.pdf
                       Bla.file.pdf             C.file.pdf
                       C.file.pdf               Delta.file.pdf
```

... should be transform into this....

```
Folder1  "contains"  folder2   "contains"  Bzzz.file.R
                     A.file.txt            1.pdf
                     1.pdf                 2.pdf
                     2.pdf                 3.pdf
```

The algorithm should be working whatever is the number of folders "and how deep is the folder inception"

If this would be working even if there are already files called 3.pdf or other number.pdf in some folders it would be a bit better but I can actually deal without this flexibility !

Thanks a lot for your help !

I ran this code but it is not totally working. If I just run it, I get this error message: "Error in if (is.na(pathname)) {  : the argument's length is zero" (I had to translate this error message from french so there might have some missmatch with an error message we can get from R in english).

Then I realized that d is weird because it contains a directory called "." at the first position that I don't have in my folder (Do you have an explanation for that by the way ?!).

so I did d<-d[-1] and rerun the big lapply I get this error message:

"Error in setwd(d[x]): impossible to change working directory"
And indeed the files in the first folder were renamed but only in the first folder

Here what list.dirs() gives:

"."        "./3.Sept" "./4.Oct"  "./5.Nov"  "./6.Dec"

But I only have 4 folders. There is no folder called "." ! And as I said if I do d<-d[-1] the code is not succeding at changing directory so that only one folder is renamed

Comment: In a given folder I want to rename all pdf files whatever are their current names. If in this folder there are 3 pdf files, they will be renamed 1.pdf, 2.pdf and 3.pdf. I don't want to rename non-pdf files. The thing is that my folder contains other folders which contains files and folders and so on. I want that in any of these folders the pdf files are renamed independently of the renaming that have done in other folders.
In my example I added non-pdf files just to show that they should not be renamed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since list.files() returns files in alphabetical order by default one way this could be achieved quite simply is the following:

```
# Navigate to top directory using setwd("my/top/directory/here")
# This code will then rename all pdfs in the current directory and ALL sub-directories
setwd( "C:/whatever/directory" )    
    # Navigate to top directory using setwd("my/top/directory/here")
d <- list.dirs()
lapply( 1:length(d) , function( x ){ 
    require( R.utils)
    f <- list.files( path = getAbsolutePath( d[x] ) , pattern = "*.pdf" , full.names = TRUE )
    lapply( seq_len( length(f) ) , function(y) {
        file.rename( f[y] , paste( dirname( f[y] ) ,"/" , y , ".pdf" , sep = "" ) )
        })
    })
```

Comment: @user2051137 I realised that I got some confusion with pathnames etc. This should work now (I have tested it!)